# Continuar código após aceitar permissões, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, android-permission

Boa Noite.
Estou tentando fazer uma pagina apenas para solicitar as permissões necessárias e depois encaminhar os usuários para outra Activity da aplicação, porem não estou conseguindo fazer com que após aceitar as permissões ele seja encaminhado, tenho que sair e entrar na aplicação ou rotacionar para ele encaminhar para próxima pagina. Sou leigo nessa linguagem se alguém puder me ajudar, já agradeço.
Abaixo o código da aplicação.

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Inico extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtpermissao;

    String[] appPermissoes = {
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    public static final int CODIGO_PERMISSOES_REQUERIDAS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inico);

        txtpermissao = findViewById(R.id.txtpermissao);

        if(verificarPermissoes()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else {
            txtpermissao.setText("Nem todas as Permissões Foram Abilitadas");
        }
    }
    public boolean verificarPermissoes(){
        List<String> permissoesRequeridas = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String permissao : appPermissoes){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissao) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissoesRequeridas.add(permissao);
            }
        }
            if(!permissoesRequeridas.isEmpty()){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissoesRequeridas.toArray(new String[permissoesRequeridas.size()]),
                        CODIGO_PERMISSOES_REQUERIDAS);
                return false;
            }
                return true;
    };

}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá!

Para implementar o fluxo de requisições de permissão de recursos no Android é preciso se atentar a alguns pontos:

1. Você sempre deve verificar se a permissão já foi garantida.
2. Você sempre deve pedir a permissão
3. E por último, você sempre deve esperar pela resposta da solicitação da permissão

Os dois pontos iniciais você cobriu no seu código. Você implementou o método verificarPermissoes() que verifica se essas permissões solicitadas já foram garantidas, e se elas não fora, você as solicita.

O que está faltado no seu código é o ponto 3: Você não está esperando a resposta da sua solicitação, e sendo assim, não tem como saber se a permissão foi garantida ou não.

Para fazer isso é simples. Na sua Activity, adicione o código abaixo:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    /*INSIRA AQUI NOVAMENTE A LOGICA QUE VERIFICA AS PERMISSOES*/
    /*AS PERMISSOES E SEUS RESULTADOS VEM NOS ARRAYS permissions e grantResults*/


}
```

Se o usuário negar uma ou mais permissões é uma boa pratica apresentar uma tela ou popup explicando para ele porque seu app precisa daquela permissão antes de solicitá-la de novo.

Para um exemplo completo, de uma olhada no [repositório da documentação oficial do android clicando aqui](https://github.com/android/permissions-samples/blob/master/RuntimePermissionsBasic/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicpermissions/MainActivity.java).